# Laravel : 3 tables linked with a central pivot. How to translate this to Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hello and thanks for reading this,

[image: Model]

A student have several courses and an individual project assigned to this course.
Multiple individual projects are available but only one by student by course.

If i want to know which individual project is assigned to student 10 for the course 1.. I could ask it this way.

```
Select Individual_project.* FROM Individual_project
INNER JOIN Students_has_Course ON Individual_project.id = 
    Students_has_Course.Individual_project_id
INNER Course ON Students_has_Course.Course_id = Course.id
INNER JOIN Students ON Students_has_Course.Students_id=Students.id
wHere Students.id=10 AND Course.id=1
```

I'm trying to translate these relations into Laravel models using Eloquent but I think that I'm missing something.

It's easy to make a relationship to find courses related to a students..

```
class Students extends Eloquent {

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Course','Students_has_Course','Course_id');
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to make a complex join to obtain a collection of students with their courses and the related individual project for each of them.

Thanks again for reading this. I hope that it is understandable. English is not my first language and It's very late. I will provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your model.  You shouldn't put courses and projects in the same pivot table.  What happens when a single student, in a single course, has 3 projects and you query your pivot table?  You get something like:

```
john doe =>
    courses =>
        course 1 =>
            project 1 data
        course 1 =>
            project 2 data
        course 1 =>
            project 3 data
```

You would be better off breaking the different relationships into separate pivot tables.  It is a bit more work, but it offers much more flexibility.  Note that I changed the table/column names to match Laravel conventions.

```
class Course extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'courses';

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project', 'course_project', 'course_id', 'project_id');
    }

    public function students() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }

}

class Student extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Course', 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project', 'project_student', 'project_id', 'student_id');
    }

}

class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Course', 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }

    public function students() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }   

}

$studentsCoursesProjects = Student::with('courses', 'courses.projects')->get()->toArray();

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John Doe
            [courses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Intro to Laravel
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [course_id] => 1
                                    [student_id] => 1
                                )

                            [projects] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [desc] => Routing
                                            [pivot] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [course_id] => 1
                                                    [project_id] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [desc] => Eloquent
                                            [pivot] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [course_id] => 1
                                                    [project_id] => 2
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

$studentsProjectsCourses = Student::with('projects', 'projects.courses')->get()->toArray();

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John Doe
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [desc] => Routing
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [student_id] => 1
                                )

                            [courses] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [name] => Intro to Laravel
                                            [pivot] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [course_id] => 1
                                                    [student_id] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Doing it this way gives you the ability to do all sorts of cool stuff with Eloquent.

```
$studentsCoursesProjectsFilter = Student::with(array('courses' => function($query) { }, 'courses.projects' => function ($query ) {
    $query->where('projects.id', 1);
}))->get()->toArray();
```

EDIT:

If changing the db model isn't an option then you can do something like this:

```
class Student extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Course', 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project', 'course_student', 'project_id', 'course_id');
    }

}
$students = Student::with('courses', 'courses.projects')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I presume that function projects should be in courses model. Also, tell me if I'm wrong but Individual_project_id should not be part of the primary key because only on project must be available by course.